# cat /dev/ttyS0 Input/output error

Tags: tty, cat, serial-port, serial-console

I created infrared receiver as in LIRC manual (http://www.lirc.org/receivers.html). And tested it on windows using program called `Terminal`.

When I switched on RTS pin DCD pin was also switched on and when I used remote controll DCD was blinking. So everything works with hardware.

Next I tried using the same hardware on Linux Mint 17 on same computer as in http://lifehacker.com/5527752/control-your-desktop-pc-with-a-remote-using-lirc but with no luck:

```
piotrek-H87-HD3 piotrek # cat /dev/ttyS0 
cat: /dev/ttyS0: Input/output error
```

I also followed http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/10218/ttys0-terminal-on-serial-connection. In this tutorial there was the same 
error I had so I tried looking in BIOS setup but serial ports were enabled.

Why isin't it working?

Some information data:

```
piotrek-H87-HD3 piotrek # cat /proc/tty/driver/serial
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:
0: uart:16550A port:000003F8 irq:4 tx:0 rx:0
1: uart:unknown port:000002F8 irq:3
2: uart:unknown port:000003E8 irq:4
3: uart:unknown port:000002E8 irq:3
4: uart:16550A port:0000F080 irq:19 tx:34 rx:0 CTS|DSR|CD
5: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0
6: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0
7: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0
8: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0
...
```

//EDIT

I was wondering lately if maybe linux somehow switched pin layout of my serial port? My motherboard COM port pins layout is :

[image: Motherboard layout]

I have back panel extension cord which maps 1:1 pin layout from motherboard to back panel like this:

```
-------------------
\ [1][3][5][7][9] /
 \  [2][4][6][8] /
  \ ___________ /
```

In windows pin order is same as in motherboard manual. **Is it possible that pins are switched somehow?** Can I check it?

Nobody seems to know the answer so maybe I ask another question. **Can I write some script (python maybe?) that will enable selected pins on /dev/ttyS0** so I could measure voltage and check which pin is which?